# Problems white date and two variables

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

I have next code:

```
SELECT * FROM lc_t_ordenes
WHERE fecha_registro between date(%s) and date(%s)+.9
ORDER BY fecha_registro ASC
```

When the date is between `2016-10-01` and `2016-10-30` it works but when I try to find only records when date is `2016-10-31` doesn´t work.

In table date is `timestamp`. How can I find records between `date1 (2016-10-01 00:00:00)` and `date2 (2016-10-01 23:59:59)`?

User only puts `2016-10-01`.

Comment: Can't you use fecha_registro >= date1 AND fecha_registro <= date2??

Comment: No does´nt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE DATE(timestamp_column) = '2016-10-01';
```

Edit to your code:

```
SELECT * FROM lc_t_ordenes
WHERE DATE(fecha_registro) BETWEEN '2016-10-01' AND '2016-10-30'
ORDER BY fecha_registro ASC;
```

Reference: [MySQL Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: but i need to use two variables, because sometimes user needs to looking between two dates and other just for one day

Answer (score 0):

You should insert date with time format
add 00:00:00 AND '23:59:59' in your variable and convert that variable to date format with the help of strtodate function
Sorry for any mistake i am not a php guy :)

```
$date1 = new DateTime('2012-05-29');
$date2 = new DateTime('2012-05-29');
$date1= $date1->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date2->modify("+23 hours");
$date2->modify("+59 minutes");  
$date2->modify("+59 seconds");
$date2= $date2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```